# passing value to child without saving it to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that im working on and im stuck on one part. 
I have a  component that i use to fetch data from a server which then I need to pass into another component.

Since this could potentially be a big payload, i don't want to use a global variable to store the data and then pass it when render gets called nor do i want to save the data to the state, as the data has nothing to do with the App component.

Is there a way in which i can pass the value that i receive from componentDidMount() to the render function and pass it as props to the desired component?

Thanks in advance!

*edit:

```
// code
componentDidMount() {
    // gets the data
}

redner() {
    return <Node value={*Needs to be passed here*} />
}
```

This snippet is all in my app component. I need to pass the data from componentDidMount() to render without using state or global variables.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand it right. You are doing server call in componentDidMount?

Comment: Yes. The call is made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` function is called every time component `props` are updated. Unless you explicitly disable it in `shouldComponentUpdate`. So you should get all the `props` changes in `render` function (if you are updating props correctly).

**EDIT**:

After updating answer I hope I understand the problem correctly.

In your case the best way is to use `state` to share data between async promise/callback and `render` method. Setting up state via `this.setState` method ensures that component is re-rendered.

Something like:

```
// code
componentDidMount() {
    // gets the data
    this.state = {}; init state
    axios.get("/data")
        .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data }));
}

redner() {
    return <Node value={this.state.data} />
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to better reflect what i was trying to explain.

Comment: Im an idiot. I completely threw out the notion that it should be stored in the top component. Sorry to have wasted your time.